# How to hide main menu while showing sub-menu in css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm creating a side-bar menu for a site, which should only show sub-menus in a currently selected page. The site is in wordpress. I have managed to hide inactive sub-menu items for pages that are not selected using this css:

```
    .sub-menu { display: none; }
    .current_page_item .sub-menu, .current_page_parent .sub-menu { display: block;}
```

But how can I hide the main menu items but still display their sub-menus? Here's [a link to the site](http://cnhr.eugenenyawara.com/media-centre/) NOTE: I want to hide ALL the main menu items so that I only have the sub-menus

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hide the current item anchor.

```
.current_page_item > a {display:none;}
```

(You may want to adjust the left margin on the sub items depending on the look you're going for.)

Comment: That works @Brian , thanks. But my intention is to hide ALL the main menu items, like on this site http://www.edctp.org/About_EDCTP.2.0.html

Comment: Not sure I see what you want in the edctp link (the top level menu items don't seem to disappear regardless of the level I navigate to) but, perhaps this: 

#menu-side-menu-1 > li > a {display:none;}